Problem with receiving solana
I bought solana on phantom with stripe like 2h agou. And i didnt receive my solana. And in my bank acc it is saying that the purchase is reserved. Do you know what should i do? (Im new)

If you haven't received your Solana after buying it through Phantom with Stripe and your bank shows the purchase as reserved, here's what you should do:
Wait a Little Longer: Sometimes transactions can take a bit more time due to network congestion or processing delays.
Check Transaction Status: Look for any confirmation emails or messages from Phantom or Stripe about the status of your transaction.
Contact Support: Reach out to Phantom's customer support and provide them with all relevant details, including your transaction ID and any email confirmations.
Monitor Your Bank Account: Keep an eye on your bank account to see if the reserved purchase clears or updates.
By taking these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue or get more information about your transaction.
